# Backed up videos won't play on the iPad they were backed up from

Tags: ios, ipad, backup, video

I was at a point where my iPad was full on storage due to huge amount of photos and documents. It was iOS 8.3 at the time. I decided to back it up and update it to iOS 10. I connected it to my PC, backed it up and updated it. It then gave me the option to restore from the back up so I did. I activated my iPad and started using it. Everything is fine, it is faster and smoother however **when I try to play videos from backed up photo album, white loading circle starts turning and does not stop. How can I fix this?**

If there is any other way to get videos from the backup file I could do that too.

Answer (score 1):

You have iCloud Photo Library'a memory saving feature activated, and either is your Internet extremely slow or you're experiencing a bug, to fix the bug restart your device.

To deactivate the memory saving feature in photos:
Settings->Photos & camera -> Save and Store originals (or some synonym for it)
This requires you have enough free space on your device for all your pictures

Information from Apple's support page: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204264

Comment: In Photos and Camera the Download and Keep Originals option was already checked and it was last updated now. About the free space, it seems to have 5 GB's of available space. Concerning the Internet speed, it is 20Mbps download, 5 upload and 11 ms ping as much as I can see from Ookla. I still couldn't find the problem.